# WebAPI interface to existing .Net code

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, asp.net-web-api

I have a VB.Net 3.5 Windows Forms project that contains code that I wish to access via a WebAPI.  The functionality in question is relatively cleanly implemented, in that it is called via a single function using one parameter, that then performs (complex) manipulation on a set of data in a MSSQL database to create more data in the same database.

The original application is logically three parts - a VB Windows Forms interface to collect data and push into the database (already recoded into a Laravel app), the data manipulation functionality, and the display of that data (to be recoded into Laravel).  We could recoded the data manipulation functionality, but it's complex, would take many man hours, and is largely self contained - so creating a WebAPI service using the existing code seems to be an easy win.

I've successfully added a simple 'Hello World' WebAPI service to the solution containing the Windows Forms project.  What's the best approach to encapsulating the functionality in the Windows Forms code into the WebAPI project?

Comment: Why are you asking for "the best approach"? What have you tried and what does or doesn't work? You'll have to think in input and output messages and form that into an API, which calls into your business logic.

Comment: Because although I've been maintaining the Windows Forms application, and I have some familiarity with .Net, I'm far from an expert on it and never done anything like this before (I spend 90% of my time with various LAMP like stacks).  I simplified slightly because there's three functions that need to be called, BUT all of them are essentially Black Box manipulation of data.  Very basic questions therefore - like can I set up a reference to the WebForms project inside the WebAPI one and use code via that or do I need to do something more bespoke?